# Models inherit fields from other models in Django

Tags: django

I have the following models. I am trying to get the newlistitem model to inherit the same image from the above, if that makes sense. I see that I passed through user as a parameter when calling listitem.user and it works fine, but can't seem to grab the picture of the related object.

## HTML Render

```
I am returning both objects to the form and call

                    {% for item in listitems %}
                    <div id = "indivlistitem">

                        
                        <b>{{item.list_name|title}}</b>

                        <li><img src="/media/{{ item.list_picture }}"/></li>
                    
                        <li>{{item|title}}</li>

                    </div>
                    
                    {% endfor %}

#MODELS
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    
    class newlist(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        list_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles/')
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.list_name
    
    class newlistitem(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User)
        list_name = models.ForeignKey(newlist)
        list_item = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
        list_picture = models.ImageField(newlist.picture)
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.list_item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, `list_picture = models.ImageField(newlist.picture)`
is not going to work.  However, it did provide some insight into what you're trying to do.

Since you already have a foreign key to a list in the newlistitem model (your list_name field), you can access the picture that it's linked to by traversing the foreign key, as such.

You'll note that I've also used the `url` property that all ImageFields contain, to automatically populate the URL of the picture:

```
{% for item in listitems %}
<div id = "indivlistitem">


<b>{{item.list_name|title}}</b>

<li><img src="{{ item.list_name.picture.url }}"/></li>

<li>{{item|title}}</li>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

***UPDATE***

Some of the pictures that you are trying to access are blank, so you will need to validate that there is an image associated with each entry.

```
{% for item in listitems %}
<div id = "indivlistitem">


<b>{{item.list_name|title}}</b>
{% if item.list_name.picture %}
    <li><img src="{{ item.list_name.picture.url }}"/></li>
{% endif %}
<li>{{item|title}}</li>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: I am trying to traverse to the picture of the foreignkey, but can't seem to get to it

Comment: When you use code like I have listed above, what does the HTML source for that portion (the img src line) look like?

Comment: I get an error. It doesn't like the 'url' portion of it. But when I omit the url portion, I see no change.

Comment: The 'picture' attribute has no file associated with it.

Comment: I'm curious what error you get, as Django's tracebacks are normally very verbose.  Do you have a MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_ROOT set up?

Comment: OK, so do all of your users have a picture uploaded? Or are some of them blank? Because this is now a very different question. :)

Comment: Yes, I have both of those set up. I can directly call the image when I use the model associated with the image, but that isn't what I am trying to do.

Comment: Some of them are blank :) is that a problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78478/discussion-between-ryan-and-junaos).